# Getting XPATH Of Dropbox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario: I want to automate: "https://www.dummyticket.com/dummy-ticket-for-visa-application/" , this page, I am able to interact with every web-element except a certain DropBox, where the XPATH is very difficult for me to find, I have tried many ways (using SelectorHub + Chropath) nothing lets my code interact with that item.

My requirement is simple: I want to interact with that dropbox, and want to select "Visa extension".

Please help me find & teach to find the right XPATH

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT5Lq.jpg)

```
import time from telnetlib import EC

from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://www.dummyticket.com/dummy-ticket-for-visa-application/")

driver.maximize_window()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='product_550']").click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='first and middle name as on passport']").send_keys("Waleed") driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='last name as on passport']").send_keys("Khan")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='dob']").click()  # opens date picker

Date_Picker_month = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@aria-label='Select month']"))

Date_Picker_month.select_by_visible_text("Dec")

Date_Picker_year = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@aria-label='Select year']"))

Date_Picker_year.select_by_visible_text("1993")

all_dates = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']/tbody/tr/td/a")

for loop

for dates in all_dates: if dates.text == "27": dates.click() break

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[1]//div[1]//form[1]//div[3]//div[1]//div[1]//p[4]//span[1]//input[1]").click() driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[1]//div[1]//form[1]//div[3]//div[1]//div[1]//p[4]//span[1]//input[1]").click() driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='fromcity']").send_keys("Pakistan") driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='tocity']").send_keys("United States Of America")

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@name,'departon')]").click() departure_month = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@class='ui-datepicker-month']"))

departure_month.select_by_visible_text("Dec")

departure_year = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@class='ui-datepicker-year']"))

departure_year.select_by_visible_text("2023")

all_dates1 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='ui-datepicker-calendar']/tbody/tr/td/a")

for loop

for departure_dates in all_dates1: if departure_dates.text == "11": departure_dates.click() break


ticketoption = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='selection']") ticketoption.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@title='Visa extension']").click()
```

This I tried but it's not working, kindly help me using my format of code, thank-you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Alright apologies, next time, I'll keep it short and concise.

Comment: When posting code, please format it as code, not a quote. Otherwise it will be unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That drop down is a special element called "Select".
Selenium has special feature to select this Select options by **index**, by **value** or by **visible text**.
Here I used the visible text approach.
The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)


url = "https://www.dummyticket.com/dummy-ticket-for-visa-application/"
driver.get(url)

select = Select(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "reasondummy"))))
select.select_by_visible_text('Visa extension')
```

The result is
[image]

Comment: Thank-you so much, thank-you for teaching me, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. This is exactly what this platform for